# How to create a button of any form programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I want to create a button with some properties.

1. It can have any form, color and placement.
2. These parameters can be changed in the application
3. The button can change its colour on touch

I try to use `Canvas`,  `Draw` and `onTouchEvent`. But is there exists more simple and fast aproach? Any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xml file like one below, to create states for your button.

You simply copy this xml file to your drawables folder in your project, name it for example custom_button.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="#00ff00" />
        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="#ff0000"
            android:dashWidth="3dp"
            android:dashGap="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ffffff"
            android:centerColor="#ffffff"
            android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#00ff00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ffffff"
            android:centerColor="#ffffff"
            android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="#00ff00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and reference it in your layout with following code in your onCreate method

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);

        //set the properties for button
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("Button");
        btnTag.setId(some_random_id);
        btnTag.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_button));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to change the form too. For example, from pizza part to star.